# Am I too heavy for Chinese hard sleeper trains?

Tags: trains, safety, china

I'm not talking about size, I'm talking about weight. I weigh 270 lbs (120 kg). I'm (irrationally?) afraid I will break my berth.

I've gone on soft sleeper class before and it was fine. But pictures of the hard sleeper class make the whole arrangement seem flimsy.

Comment: You would be fine at the bottom level of the 3 level sleeping arrangement

Comment: I'm travelling with 3 other people, so if we are placed in the same room then I'll definitely be able to call dibs on the lower level. And I'm sure no Chinese people will want me above them :-)

Comment: When you buy your tickets, that's when you need to tell them you want the bottom... I think, I haven't bought a ticket in awhile

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Since I just have the train registration number, I probably cannot see what exact seats we have until I pick up the tickets at the train station. I imagine it's likely that they aren't actually assigned until they're picked up, so I'll show up early anyway as I hope for all 4 of us to be placed close or in the same room. Hopefully with 4 tickets purchased blind luck will allow at least one ticket to be the bottom bunk, and maybe I'll try to request a bottom bunk, but it is during Spring Festival.

Comment: It's gonna be busy, going to china during any kind of festival or national holidays, it's very busy everywhere

Comment: I know, I've been there during Spring Festival! It was a little crazy but it was really fun too! To be honest, I knew when posting this question that I'm probably overthinking this aspect of my trip. I'm not concerned about the huge list of things that scared me about my first time in China, so now I'm worried about dumb little things like this!

Comment: Wait..  270 lbs is NOT 220 kgs - it's 120kg.  Are you saying your weight is 270lbs/120kg, or 485lbs/220kg??

Comment: What @Doc said.

Comment: 120kg (fixed)

And all the berths are fine, yes, my fears were unfounded. It was fun to go up to the very top one but I'm also glad I didn't have to sleep up there!

Comment: Yup, at 120KG you'll be fine.  220KG as originally stated would likely be a different story!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By hard sleeper class I assume you are talking about this

[image]

If this is the case, then you will for sure be ok with the bottom level. As for the other 2 levels, I am not 100% sure, I think I have seen the max weight on those but I cannot recall at the moment

Comment: Yeah those are the ones. You can see how I'd be concerned about the small supports near the ladders for my fatness. I'm sure nobody will want me above them anyway and I can get the lowest level.

Comment: Honestly I have seen some heavier guys on the train but of course I have no idea how much they actually weigh. You will be the safest at the bottom... unless another big guy is on the 2nd or the 3rd level

Comment: After this experience, I'd say all three levels could easily take someone my weight or even quite a bit heavier. They're more solid than they look in pictures for sure! And it was a great (though long) trip! Kunming was fantastic!

Comment: @alexk I know this is relatively old. Since this answer actually waffles about the upper two bunks, and you were positive about not having issues with them, why not make your own answer and accept it. It's not only allowed, [it's encouraged](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 10):

When I first came to China, I was 132 kg. I travelled on the hard sleepers on the middle and top bunks and there was no problem. The beds are solid construction and would take much more than my weight to break them.

Comment: The problem with that logic is that the person asking the question does have "much more than [your] weight", so...

Comment: @Doc No, it's 120kg. (Fixed now).

Answer (score 6):

Been there, done that, in 2008.  Maybe closer to 250 than 270, but I was not worried about the bunk collapsing.  I've seen couples in bunks, so it holds two (smaller) people.

I was more concerned with *fitting* in the bunk.

I don't know why I was assigned the topmost bunk.

Comment: Unless things have changed recently, top is the cheapest (and middle is a bit more than bottom). Everyone sits on the bottom bunk during the day. For bottom bunk I think these characters should do it: 下铺

Comment: We were a group of 4.   As a family, we had one stack of three on the left plus one of the bunks on the right (I don't recall which). The decision of who gets which bunk was decided within the family.

Comment: Sitting on the bottom is not possible when the middle bunk is at the level of my neck.  It's a general problem I faced travelling in China.